# how to find youtube url from a content in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get youtube url from input field . I am using preg_match to find my url . But my current preg_match removing '_' in url.

my current script:

```
preg_match_all('/https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/[^\s]*v\=|youtu\.be\/)([a-z0-9]+)/is', $content, $youtubes);
```

Problem with url like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kE_dchnyPwo . See it's removing the '_' and the content after it 'dchnyPwo' .

Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, try this: /https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/[^\s]*v\=|youtu\.be\/)([_a-z0-9]+)/is

Comment: thanks a lot it's working

Answer (score 0):

Sure it works ...

You will get youtube v= value from this code using php
`<?php $_POST['utube_upload']='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kro_oGu3Wzk';
$youtube_url=$_POST['utube_upload'];
$useurl = explode("?",$youtube_url);
echo str_replace("v=","",$useurl[1]); ?>`